# inline element with background-clip: text; in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

It is wired in **Safari** browser using `background-clip: text;` to realize the gradient color text of **inline** element( **fig. 1** ). When changing the display to `inline-block` or `block` it seems ok, but I prefer an inline effect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npvb1.png)

I'm wondering how can I realize the same visual effect just as the Chrome shows( **fig. 2** )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Kcb.png)

Here are the code, any help would be appreciated :)

```js
import React from 'react';

import './demo.css'

const Demo = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="text">When the rain is blowing in your face and the whole world is on your case, <span className="highlight">I could offer you a warm embrace to make you feel my love. </span>To make you feel my love.
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Demo;
```

```css
/* demo.css */
.container {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, red, blue);
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'display:inline; and -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
like this...

```
.test {
    display: inline;
    background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, red, blue);;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
<div>
  <p class="test">The background extends behind the border.</p>
<div>
```